# JqueryUI autocomplete returns wrong item on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I used JqueryUI on this project im working on.
When I focus on the next item in the list with the down arrow key, jqueryui returns the previous selected item

[Here's a perfect working sample is here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCd4J/15/)

Here's the Jquery code

```
$( "#itemname" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
        }, 
        //focus: function(event) { alert( event.type ); }
        focus : function(event, ui) { 
            //alert( $(this).val() );
            var item_name_this = $(this).val();
            $('#properties_item_name').html(item_name_this);               
        }
});
```

Comment: It is probably due to zero based indexing that `$(this).val()` is messed up. Use `ui.item.val` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
focus: function (event, ui) {
     var item_name_this = ui.item.value;
     $('#properties_item_name').html(item_name_this);
}
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/VCd4J/16/

Comment: thanks a lot, it work like charm, ive spent a day trying to solve this mystery, it all started from how to get the `focus` event to fire. You really made my day. :):D @};-